# One consolidated regex for below inputes

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone give consolidated regex for below inputs?

```
1. interface eth1/10.404 p2p 
2. interface ae0.100 p2p
3. interface pool0 multibind lastresort
4. interface loop0 loopback
5. interface ae0.100
6. interface loop0
```

I have created one but it is not giving me the desired output:

```
/^\sinterface\s(((\w*\/*\w*.\w*)\s(\w*.*))|((\w*\/*\w*.\w*)))/
```

The output I require is that from each input I receive the value as:

1. - 1st group: eth1/10.404
   - 2nd group: p2p
2. - 1st group: ae0.100
   - 2nd group: p2p
3. - 1st group: pool0
   - 2nd group: multibind lastresort
4. - 1st group: loop0
   - 2nd group: loopback
5. - 1st group: ae0.100
6. - 1st group: loop0

The above regex is not working for 3 inputs.

Comment: Does your input have numbered data, or have you just numbered the examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't regex, use `split`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
   chomp;
   next unless /interface/;
   my ( undef, undef, $if_name, $options ) = split / /, $_, 4;
   print "$if_name => ",$options // '(none)',"\n";
}

__DATA__
1. interface eth1/10.404 p2p 
2. interface ae0.100 p2p
3. interface pool0 multibind lastresort
4. interface loop0 loopback
5. interface ae0.100
6. interface loop0
```

Uses `//` which is the 'defined' conditional, to return either the value or the string '(none)'.

output:

```
eth1/10.404 => p2p 
ae0.100 => p2p
pool0 => multibind lastresort
loop0 => loopback
ae0.100 => (none)
loop0 => (none)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while(<>) {
    next unless m{interface\s+(\S+)(\s+(.+))?\s*$};
    print "1st group:-$1";
    print " 2nd group:-$3" if $3 ne '';
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have simple space-separated data. It looks like this might be an easier solution:

```
if ($line =~ /^interfaces/) {
    chomp($line);
    my @fields = split(/ /, $line, 3);

    # Use $fields[1], and use $fields[2] if it is defined.
    # Check with e.g., scalar(@fields) == 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\s*interface\s(\S+)(.*)?
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Xvsq769leN).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me :

`interface(\s[\w\d\/.]+)(.*)?`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/iV4vA3/1)